# Unable to set Socket Timeout less than 1000 milliseconds in RequestConfig (Apache HTTP async client 4.1.2)

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpasyncclient

Following is my code

```
       RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setSocketTimeout(100)
                .setConnectTimeout(100)
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(100).build();


        CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                .build();

        httpClient.start();
```

According to setSocketTimeout value, it should timeout in 100 ms, but it is taking 1000 ms to timeout. setSocketTimeout is honouring all value greater than 1000 ms, though.

Comment: 100ms is far too short for a read timeout or a connect timeout.

Comment: @EJP 1000 ms seems to be minimum value allowed for socket timeout. Any value less than 1000 ms is being set as 1000.

Comment: By this framework. Not by Java.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This behavior is intentional. The i/o selector threads need to iterate over existing i/o sessions on a regular basis and trigger socket timeout event in case of i/o inactivity. This operation can get very expensive especially as the number of concurrent sessions grows. By default the i/o select interval is set to 1000 ms, and therefore the granularity of socket timeout by default is 1 sec. One can reduce the select interval and make i/o selector threads iterate over sessions more often at the cost of greater CPU utilization. With select interval of 1ms i/o selector threads will effectively run in a busy loop.

```
IOReactorConfig ioReactorConfig = IOReactorConfig.custom()
        .setSelectInterval(100)
        .setSoTimeout(100)
        .setConnectTimeout(100)
        .build();
CloseableHttpAsyncClient httpClient = HttpAsyncClients.custom()
        .setDefaultIOReactorConfig(ioReactorConfig)
        .build();
```